# Prevent double click on MFC-Dialog button

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, event-handling, double-click

i'm developing Autocad/Bricscad-Dialogs in MFC C++. Know i detected a bigger problem. There is a dialog which sets metadata for 'special' drawing objects. I update the data of every 'special' drawing object with this dialog (in a loop). So if you have ten 'special' drawing objects, the same dialog will open ten times (successively). Now i have the problem that the user sometimes make a double click on the "OK"-Button. But if this double click is fast enough, the "OK"-Button of the next instance of this dialog will clicked automatically. I tried a lot (for example disabling the button if it was clicked) but nothing solved my problem. Maybe someone of you have a good idea.

Best regards,
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a new dialog you can flush the message queue of mouse click messages before going into your normal message loop, e.g.:

```
MSG msg;
while (PeekMessage(&msg, hWndDlg, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, PM_REMOVE));
```

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand what you mean but i don't have an "own" message loop for the dialogs. I only have a loop with .DoModal() calls for every dialog/drawing object.

Comment: No matter if you have an own message loop or not, just do as Jonathan Potter says.

Comment: Your dialog's message loop is in MFC code. Putting Jonathan Potter's suggestion in the dialog's OnInitDialog should do the trick.

Comment: Ok i have it but it don't works in OnInitDialog. I tried it in the constructor and now it works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Ok it does not work yet. If i debug it it work perfekt but if i try it without debugger it doesn't work. I hate this...

Comment: You should probably also remove all `WM_LBUTTONUP` and `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` messages from the queue.

Comment: Yeah using `WM_MOUSEFIRST` and `WM_MOUSELAST` would probably be the best way to do it.

Comment: The solution existent at the time on http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_10287063.html#a2476475 I used it worked well to solve. It it is now invisible, but here it goes:
  MSG msg;
  while(PeekMessage(&msg,0,WM_LBUTTONUP,WM_LBUTTONUP,PM_REMOVE));

Notice the Zero passed as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I try to extend the answer of Jonathan Potter.

When you open a new dialog and OnInitDIalog is called, just remove the mouse messages from the queue and wait for 1/10 of a second.

```
MSG msg;
DWORD dwStart = ::GetTickCount():
while (PeekMessage(&msg, hWndDlg, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, PM_REMOVE)!=0 ||
       (::GetTickCount() - dwStart) < 100))
      ;
```

The trick with the PeekMessage will work, the problem is that you need to run the loop as long as a "double click" will take. If the clicks have a distance of 1/10th of a second you need to remove all mouse clicks for this period of time.

And also OnInitDialog is the correct position. You may extend this flush to all mouse messages WM_MOUSEFIRST/WM_MOUSELAST... to get all clicks.

The delay of 1/10 second when launching the next dialog isn't expensive or annoying.

Comment: Thanks for this input but i do it on an other way:
In the OnInitDialog() method i never got an mouse click event. Now i call the code from Jonathan just before the EndDialog() method. I remove all mouse click events. Now it works fine! Thank you for helping.

Comment: Remember that the second click might not be in the queue when EndDialog is executed! This is the major problem. I had a similar problem with a construct like this.